# Est-ce qu'on peut dire lisable au lieu de lisible ?

Tags: jargon

Ma question est très simple: est-ce qu'on peut dire et écrire "lisable" au lieu de "lisible".
Dans ce cas, pouvez-vous me dire où ce mot est utilisé ?
Peut-être dans quelque region spécifique ?
Ou est-ce simplement incorrect ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sur [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/lisable) on indique que c'est une variante de *lisible* en français d'Amérique du Nord (Québec, Acadie, Louisiane) ; je l'ai déjà entendu mais je ne l'emploierais pas à l'écrit au lieu de *lisible*. On indique aussi que ce peut être employé rarement et de manière non standard pour signifier « qui peut être lu », mais possiblement de manière différente du sens de *lisible* et l'exemple suivant est particulièrement utile ici :

> Ce n’est donc pas tant que ce soit *illisible (incompréhensible)* : on
> dirait plutôt que ce n’est pas **lisable**, que ça exige un autre
> protocole, une autre physique de la lecture (son passage au sonore, à
> la voix « haute » ?). (Christian Prigent, *Ceux qui merdRent*, P.O.L.,
> 1991, page 188, exemple ds. *Wiktionnaire*)

Autrement ça s'est sans doute employé il y a [très](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/lisable?idf=complXrmYXbaedaf;str=0) [longtemps](https://lecteur-few.atilf.fr/index.php/page/lire/e/158182).

---

Normalement non.

Comment: Réponse valible !